# Object doesn't support property or method IE9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9

I am having an issue with using SlimScroll with IE9. It seems to work in all other browsers but IE9.  Googling round theres a few different possibilities of the issue but I am really not sure.  I cannot see why this wouldn't work especially as it seems to work in the older IE browsers.  The easiest way to see the error is to go to: http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll.

Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'slimScroll'

Code around the area:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#slimtest1').slimScroll({
height: '200px'
});
```

My jQuery knowledge is sub-par but from what I can tell this is likely to be an issue with IE9 and jQuery. How I would go about resolving this, I have no clue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have this problem locally on by visiting the slimScroll website ?

I get the same error actually when I visit the site with IE9. Looking at the console there is this message:

```
SEC7112: Script from https://raw.github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/master/slimScroll.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch
```

The javascript file is indeed included in the html like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/master/slimScroll.js"></script>
```

In Chrome, looking at the Network tab of the console, you can see the script is sent from gitHub with "text/plain" MIME type, I guess this is what IE9 complaints about:

[image]

The file is transfered from GitHub with a wrong MIME type and IE considers this as a security problem and does not download the script. So when the plugin is not initialized and a call to `$(...).slimScrol()` raises an error.

If you download the package and try it locally it works nice in IE9.

Anyway, i don't think it is a good idea to reference files from GitHub directly ast GH is not a CDN but a source code repository.

Comment: Brilliant, this was exactly the issue and it seems that the developer has also noticed and fixed the issue already.  Thanks once again!